# Make normal character insert multiple characters in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

I'm trying to write a Prolog mode for CodeMirror, while I'm mostly a JavaScript and CodeMirror newbie.  I'm now looking into some specific layout tasks.  One of the Prolog layout styles for if-then-else is

```
head(Arg) :-
    (   if
    ->  then
    ;   else
    ).
```

The editor I use (SWI-Prolog's PceEmacs) achieves this by making (, > and ; active characters
and see whether we are in an if-then-else.  Typing "(" will insert "(   ", typing > with a
preceding "-" will align and insert "->  " and similar for ";".  The closest I can see is using
electricChars ">;", which lets me indent ok, but doesn't let me add white space after the punctuation. How is that done?

Answer (score 2):

Bind a key to, for example `"'('"`, and in your handler function, see whether your context applies, and if it does, call `.replaceSelection("( ", "end")`, if not, return `CodeMirror.Pass` to let the default behavior happen.